# How to just show the time not the time AND date?

Tags: javascript, date, time, timeofday

```
<html> 
    <p id="time"></p> 
  
    <script> 
      var theDate = new Date(Date.parse( 
        '06/14/2020 9:41:48 PM UTC')); 

 document.getElementById("time") 
        .innerHTML = theDate.toLocaleString(); 
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

When I remove the date which is "06/14/2020" in this example it tells me "Invalid date". I just want to show the time alone, without the date. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print only the time, use `toLocaleTimeString`.

Nore about Datefunction you can find at [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

Do it that way

```js
var interval = setInterval(currentTime,1000);
function currentTime(){
    var time = new Date();
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

```html
<p id="time"></p>
```